# Publishing a Python package to a private repo using Poetry with SSH

Tags: bitbucket, python-packaging, python-poetry, private-repository

I have written a Python package using Poetry and would like to upload it to a private repository on Bitbucket. Currently I can only push/pull using SSH (not HTTPS). I've managed to build the tar.gz and .whl files successfully, but I'm not sure how to configure the settings in Poetry to publish the package - All the documentation I've seen centres around using HTTPS.

So far I've tried

```
poetry config repositories.bitbucket "git@bitbucket.org:company/repo_name.git"
poetry publish --build --repository bitbucket
```

Where git@bitbucket.org:... was taken from the SSH clone prompt on the bitbucket page.

This gave the error:

```
No connection adapters were found for 'git@bitbucket.org:company/repo_name.git'
```